# kobject: "(null)" (00000000d6585cf7): is not initialized, yet kobject_get() is being called

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I get this error when I try to register a device with `device_register()`. I am trying to register a device within the bus I created and get this error.

Here is how my bus is created and registered

```c
// my_bus creation
struct bus_type my_bus = {
        .name = "my_bus",
        .match = my_match,
        .uevent = my_uevent,
};

// my_bus registration in __init function
        int err;
        err = bus_register(&my_bus);
        if (err) {
                printk(KERN_ALERT "bus registration error\n");
                return -1;
        }
```

Then I create a struct with embedded `struct device`, I set the variables of the device like init_name and then try to register where I get that error. Here is how I register the device.

```c
// device register function 
int dev_register(struct my_device *my_device)
{
        printk(KERN_DEBUG "DEVICE NAME = %s\n", my_device->name);

        my_device->dev.bus = &my_bus;
        my_device->dev.parent = &parent;
        dev_set_name(&my_device->dev, my_device->name);

        my_device->dev.groups = dev_groups;   

        return device_register(&my_device->dev);
}
```

Here is the kernel log:

```
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962870] DEVICE NAME = mydev
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962872] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962873] kobject: '(null)' (000000000b0cedc4): is not initialized, yet kobject_get() is being called.
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962879] WARNING: CPU: 5 PID: 5084 at lib/kobject.c:656 kobject_get+0x44/0x70
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962883] Modules linked in: devdas(OE+) xt_conntrack(E) xt_MASQUERADE(E) nf_conntrack_netlink(E) xfrm_user(E) xfrm_algo(E) nft_counter(E) xt_addrtype(E) nft_compat(E) nft_chain_nat(E) nf_nat(E) nf_conntrack(E) nf_defrag_ipv6(E) nf_defrag_ipv4(E) nf_tables(E) libcrc32c(E) nfnetlink(E) br_netfilter(E) bridge(E) stp(E) llc(E) overlay(E) rfkill(E) binfmt_misc(E) snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl(E) snd_sof_intel_hda_common(E) snd_sof_intel_hda(E) snd_sof_pci(E) nls_ascii(E) snd_sof(E) nls_cp437(E) vfat(E) fat(E) snd_sof_xtensa_dsp(E) snd_soc_skl(E) snd_soc_hdac_hda(E) snd_hda_ext_core(E) snd_soc_sst_ipc(E) snd_soc_sst_dsp(E) snd_soc_acpi_intel_match(E) snd_soc_acpi(E) snd_soc_core(E) snd_hda_codec_realtek(E) snd_compress(E) snd_hda_codec_generic(E) ledtrig_audio(E) snd_hda_codec_hdmi(E) snd_hda_intel(E) snd_intel_dspcfg(E) intel_rapl_msr(E) snd_hda_codec(E) intel_rapl_common(E) snd_hda_core(E) x86_pkg_temp_thermal(E) joydev(E) snd_hwdep(E) intel_powerclamp(E) snd_pcm(E) coretemp(E) snd_timer(E)
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962907]  iTCO_wdt(E) intel_pmc_bxt(E) kvm_intel(E) snd(E) iTCO_vendor_support(E) sg(E) watchdog(E) kvm(E) mei_me(E) soundcore(E) mei(E) irqbypass(E) rapl(E) intel_pch_thermal(E) acpi_pad(E) intel_cstate(E) pcspkr(E) intel_uncore(E) evdev(E) efi_pstore(E) wmi_bmof(E) intel_pmc_core(E) sunrpc(E) configfs(E) fuse(E) efivarfs(E) ip_tables(E) x_tables(E) autofs4(E) ext4(E) crc32c_generic(E) crc16(E) mbcache(E) jbd2(E) hid_generic(E) usbhid(E) hid(E) sd_mod(E) t10_pi(E) crc_t10dif(E) crct10dif_generic(E) nouveau(E) mxm_wmi(E) i2c_algo_bit(E) drm_ttm_helper(E) ttm(E) crct10dif_pclmul(E) crct10dif_common(E) crc32_pclmul(E) crc32c_intel(E) drm_kms_helper(E) ahci(E) libahci(E) ghash_clmulni_intel(E) cec(E) r8169(E) aesni_intel(E) realtek(E) libaes(E) libata(E) mdio_devres(E) crypto_simd(E) xhci_pci(E) libphy(E) scsi_mod(E) xhci_hcd(E) cryptd(E) i2c_i801(E) i2c_smbus(E) drm(E) usbcore(E) fan(E) wmi(E) video(E) button(E)
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962936] CPU: 5 PID: 5084 Comm: insmod Tainted: G           OE     5.12.0-rc8-eudyptula+ #3
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962938] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. B360M GAMING HD/B360M GAMING HD, BIOS F12 03/14/2019
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962939] RIP: 0010:kobject_get+0x44/0x70
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962941] Code: f0 41 0f c1 44 24 38 85 c0 74 33 78 21 83 c0 01 78 1c 4c 89 e0 41 5c c3 48 8b 37 48 89 fa 48 c7 c7 08 d1 50 a1 e8 04 ca 3c 00 <0f> 0b eb c8 be 01 00 00 00 e8 4e 76 fc ff 4c 89 e0 41 5c c3 be 02
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962942] RSP: 0018:ffffb67b03f73d68 EFLAGS: 00010286
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962943] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: ffff9422e5d58708
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962944] RDX: 00000000ffffffd8 RSI: 0000000000000027 RDI: ffff9422e5d58700
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962945] RBP: ffffffffc0f86320 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffffb67b03f73b88
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962946] R10: ffffb67b03f73b80 R11: ffffffffa16c2f88 R12: ffffffffc0f86320
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962947] R13: ffffb67b03f73e90 R14: 0000000000000003 R15: ffffffffc0f86048
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962948] FS:  00007f1812c03540(0000) GS:ffff9422e5d40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962949] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962950] CR2: 0000558896b1c258 CR3: 000000012372c002 CR4: 00000000003706e0
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962951] Call Trace:
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962954]  device_add+0xcb/0x850
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962958]  ? 0xffffffffc0fa7000
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962960]  dev_init+0x5e/0x1000 [devdas]
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962962]  do_one_initcall+0x44/0x1d0
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962965]  ? do_init_module+0x23/0x260
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962966]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0xfd/0x200
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962969]  do_init_module+0x5c/0x260
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962971]  __do_sys_finit_module+0xb1/0x110
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962973]  do_syscall_64+0x33/0x80
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962975]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xae
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962977] RIP: 0033:0x7f1812d249b9
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962978] Code: 00 c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d a7 54 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962979] RSP: 002b:00007ffcdc282a98 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962981] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000558896b19790 RCX: 00007f1812d249b9
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962981] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 000055889668d358 RDI: 0000000000000003
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962982] RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00007f1812dee640
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962983] R10: 0000000000000003 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 000055889668d358
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962984] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000558896b19760 R15: 0000000000000000
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962985] ---[ end trace f87cf4b7f0e5b460 ]---
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962986] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jun  3 17:46:46 reb0rn kernel: [ 4069.962987] refcount_t: addition on 0; use-after-free
```

I guess the function `device_register()` calls `dev_add()` which in return has something to do with kobject initialization. But I never read anywhere that kobject initialization is required to register the device. I tried registering device without attaching to the bus, and never required to initialize kobject. But this time I tried registering with the bus and this error pops up. I don't know how this is related but just a heads up!

Comment: It seems to be failing on the line `parent = get_device(dev->parent);` in `device_add()`. `dev->parent` is set to `&parent` in your code. So I guess `parent` in your code has not been set up correctly.

Comment: ig so yes. But I deleted the parent setup and now I get some faulty segmentation error. Not sure what that is